# How to enable concepts with g++ 6.2.0?

Tags: c++, stl, c++-concepts

Here is a code I've tried out to test the c++-concepts feature. However it does not seem to work even after using the flag -fconcepts on g++ 6.2.0 version.
Any help to get it working would be great!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std::literals;

template<typename ptr_t >
requires RandomAccessIterator<ptr_t> 
void mysort(ptr_t first, ptr_t last)
{
    sort(first, last);
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> v{22, 11, 55, 33, 44};
    list<int> l{22, 11, 55, 33, 44};
    mysort(begin(v), end(v));
    mysort(begin(l), end(l));
}
```

This is how I compile it:

```
g++-6 concepts.cpp -fconcepts
```

This is the error I get:

```
error: ‘RandomAccessIterator’ was not declared in this scope
```

I changed the spelling to `random_access_iterator` but it still does not work.

The document [C++ Working Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4620.pdf) in section 6.2.13 defines the presence of RandomAccessIterator.

Comment: Where is your concept `RandomAccessIterator` defined?

Comment: `RandomAccessIterator ` is not provided by the standard library. You need to define it.

Comment: How should I define it? What would be the exact signature?

Comment: @VarunRao: the requirements are here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator

Comment: So the standard doesnt implement a a concept for RandomAccessIterator? But the working draft in the link mentions the presence of the same. How do I use the one defined by the standard?

Comment: It's an ethereal concept. It doesn't actually exist in code, it's just there for the purpose of showing what requirements the things that use it have.

Comment: @VarunRao: the document you linked is about **ranges**. Also please note that concepts are not even part of the standard yet - `-fconcepts` is an experimental flag that can be used to play around with the feature and provide feedback. `RandomAccessIterator` might be provided by the standard/ranges in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`RandomAccessIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) is not *(yet)* provided by the Standard Library. You need to define it.

The [relevant documentation on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) is a good place to get started with the concept's requirements.

The document you linked, [N4620](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4620.pdf), is the working draft **for Ranges**, not for Concepts. Unless you include an implementation of ranges that is `-fconcepts` friendly you will not get `RandomAccessIterator` defined for you.

As [Tristan Brindle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2797826/tristan-brindle) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43590026/598696), [**`cmcstl2`**](https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2) is the reference implementation for the Ranges TS.

Answer (score 1):

The Concepts TS doesn't actually include any standard concepts such as `RandomAccessIterator`. These are being worked on in a separate [Ranges TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4651.pdf).

The reference implementation of the Ranges TS is available at https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2.